# SnapHack Library issues, "Error: UNAUTHORIZED" api call

Tags: php, api

im trying to use SnapHacks Library, but im having issues with the Api Call.

The library can be found here https://github.com/jasonanovak/snaphaxpy

When i make this Api Call:

```
$opts['username'] = $_POST['u'];
$opts['password'] = $_POST['p'];
$opts['debug'] = TRUE;

$s = new Snaphax($opts);
$result = $s->login();
```

I get the response:

SNAPHAX DEBUG: p1: m198sOkJEn37DjqZ32lpRu76xmw288xSQ9 SNAPHAX DEBUG: p2: 1.37216038466E+12 SNAPHAX DEBUG: s1: iEk21fuwZApXlz93750dmW22pw389dPwOkm198sOkJEn37DjqZ32lpRu76xmw288xSQ9 SNAPHAX DEBUG: s2: 1.37216038466E+12iEk21fuwZApXlz93750dmW22pw389dPwOk SNAPHAX DEBUG: s3: 93046e57a3c183186e9e24ebfda7ca04e7eb4d8119060a8a39b48014d4c5172b SNAPHAX DEBUG: s4: bfea75d4e369551c251cff3a308f9c4a23f96c75f9ef161068a7c7946713da57 SNAPHAX DEBUG: out: 930a7554e36155186e1cffeaf0af9c4423e94d8519ef1a8069b4c714d7c51a5b SNAPHAX DEBUG: POST params: {"username":"MyUsername","password":"MyPassword","timestamp":1.37216038466e+12,"req_token":"930a7554e36155186e1cffeaf0af9c4423e94d8519ef1a8069b4c714d7c51a5b"} SNAPHAX DEBUG: HTTP response code401 SNAPHAX DEBUG: POST return
Error: UNAUTHORIZED

```
function login() {
    $ts = $this->api->time();
    $out = $this->api->postCall(
        '/ph/login',
        array(
            'username' => $this->options['username'],
            'password' => $this->options['password'],
            'timestamp' => $ts
        ),
        $this->options['static_token'], 
        $ts
    );


    if (is_array($out) &&
            !empty($out['auth_token'])) {
        $this->auth_token = $out['auth_token'];
    }
    return $out;
}
```

$out does not return the token

If anyone is familiar with the Library or the Snapchat API, help would be apriciated

Answer (score 2):

In snaphax.php change the time function like so to return the timestamp as a string:

```
    function time() {
        return round(microtime(false) * 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp should be a string. In your POST request it's showing up as a long which Snapchat doesn't recognize, so it marks your auth token as invalid

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp string is incorrect this is because your precision is set wrong in php.ini

it should be precision=  16

change this to correct the problem; or use something like so as a workaround

```
function time() {
                        round(microtime(true) * 1000);
                        return round(preg_replace('/(0)\.(\d+) (\d+)/', '$3$1$2', microtime(1)));


                }
```